# What does "that argument" refer to in the first chapter of SICP?

Tags: meaning-in-context

It might be frivolous, but I are not aware where to ask the question.

I am reading SICP and very confused about its description about a dummy simple concept of scope : [Local Name](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-10.html#%_sec_1.1.8)

> This principle -- that the meaning of a procedure should be
> independent of the parameter names used by its author -- seems on the
> surface to be self-evident, but its consequences are profound. The
> simplest consequence is that the parameter names of a procedure must
> be local to the body of the procedure. For example, we used square in
> the definition of good-enough? in our square-root procedure:
>
> (define (good-enough? guess x)   (< (abs (- (square guess) x)) 0.001))
>
> The intention of the author of good-enough? is to determine if the
> square of the first argument is within a given tolerance of the second
> argument. We see that the author of good-enough? used the name guess
> to refer to the first argument and x to refer to the second argument.
> The argument of square is guess. If the author of square used x (as
> above) to refer to **that argument**, we see that the x in good-enough?
> must be a different x than the one in square. Running the procedure
> square must not affect the value of x that is used by good-enough?,
> because that value of x may be needed by good-enough? after square is
> done computing.

I am stuck with

> If the author of square used x (as above) to refer to **that argument**,
> we see that the x in good-enough? must be a different x than the one
> in square. Running the procedure square must not affect the value of x
> that is used by good-enough?, because that value of x may be needed by
> good-enough? after square is done computing.

What's 'that argument' refer to?

Did the author said switching x and guess?

Comment: "The **argument of square is guess**. If the author of square used x (as above) to refer to **that argument**, ... "

Comment: thank you very much,  I got it, but it's not a good illustration, cos, guess and x are initially get passed from good-enough? just from the second interation,  guess in square will not be affetctd since it is re-assigned.. confused with author to explain it in this way.. @MichaelHarvey

Answer (score 1):

"That argument" is `guess`, i.e. the first (and only) argument passed to `square`.

If you're wondering if there is a rule to help you determine, on the basis of grammar alone, what **that** refers to, the answer is no. Often the referent of **that** is grammatically ambiguous, so you must sort it out according to what makes the most sense in the context.

The context here is the use of the name `x` to refer to different things in different places in the program. If you typed the following into Scheme:

```
(define (square x) (* x x))

(define (good-enough? guess x) (< (abs (- (square guess) x)) 0.001))

(good-enough? 2.01 4)
```

then, while the last line was being evaluated, `x` would refer to 2.01 inside `square` and `x` would refer to 4 inside `good-enough?`.